# When reading multiple topics in kafka how can I tell the topic of a specific message?

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-kafka-dotnet

I am working in C# and have the following:

```
consumer.Subscribe( new string[] {"topic1", "topic2"});
var cr = consumer.Consume();
console.Write($"key {cr.Message.Key}\r\nvalue {cr.Message.Value}");
```

How do I get the topic of a specific message when I am listening to more than 1 topic?

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I was looking for it under cr.Message.  It is cr.Topic.

Answer (score 2):

The Consume function returns a ConsumeResult. This has a Topic attribute

https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/master/src/Confluent.Kafka/ConsumeResult.cs#L32

Comment: The link looks broken. Are you able to provide more details please? Or perhaps updated doc link?

Comment: What exactly is unclear? When you consume a record and get a ConsumeResult object, you can read `.Topic` attribute